# How do I run my python application daily three times

Tags: python-2.7, scheduled-tasks

I have a python application which creates JSON files. I need to execute an application three times per day at midnight, noon and evening.

```
import json 

def add():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = a+b 
    f = open("add.json","w")
    f.write(str(c))
def subtract():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = b-a 
    f = open("subtract.json","w")
    f.write(str(c))
add()
subtract()
```

I need to run the application at a specified time automatically

Comment: Your code don't create any `JSON` !!!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities :

1- Let your code run with some timer !

**For windows user:**

2- use the [AT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313565/how-to-use-the-at-command-to-schedule-tasks) command to create 3 scheduled tasks!

**For Linux user:**

2- use the [Cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) command to create 3 scheduled tasks !

which seems to be the best solution in your case!

Comment: I am a Linux user.

Comment: Read my answer for linux user !! the 2b part !!

Comment: 28 18 * * * /home/name/Desktop/python add.py. I scheduled cronjob, But it did not create any files.